# Not sure what I am doing wrong in binary search

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have a binary search and I tried to paper trace it, in my account it should return the value as true in the second iteration of the while loop, only the base case is running in console.log , I have no idea what I am doing wrong here, would love some pointers

```
const binarySearch = (sortedArray,value ) =>{

let left =0 
let right = sortedArray.length-1
let middle =left+Math.floor((right-left ) /2)
// console.log(`
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// left ==${left}

// right ==${right}

// middle==${middle}

// is value === middle??? ${value === sortedArray[middle]}

// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

// `)
while(left<right){
  if(sortedArray[middle] === value){
    return middle
  }

  if(sortedArray[middle] < value){
    left = middle+1
  }

   if(sortedArray[middle] > value){
    right = middle-1
  }

}

  return -1


}


binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5], 4)
```

edit:I found the bug! I thought for some strange reason that the while loop would use the updated middle value, but there is no reason for it to, as javascript just keeps going on the call stack unless specifically I modify some value. Then I had another issue where I was not accounting if left or right could be the value, it seems to work now, would love some tips for improvement or advice, thanks.

```
const binarySearch = (sortedArray,value ) =>{

let left =0 
let right = sortedArray.length-1

while(left<=right){

let middle =left+Math.floor((right-left ) /2)


  if(sortedArray[middle] === value){
    return middle
  }

  if(sortedArray[middle] < value){
    left = middle+1
  }

   if(sortedArray[middle] > value){
    right = middle-1
  }

}

  return -1


}


binarySearch([1,2,3,4,5], 1)
```

Comment: Well, never setting `middle` inside the loop is a bad sign.

Comment: yes, I caught that one, do you see an issue as to me saying while left <= right, as I see others use while left<right, but as I trace it out, if I want the last index, I will never reach it, using math.floor that it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main issue I see over here is that you're not updating your middle pointer every time you're updating the left and right pointers... You have to figure out what's the new middle pointer of either of the sub arrays:

```
const binarySearch = (sortedArray, value) => {
  let left = 0;
  let right = sortedArray.length - 1;
  let middle = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2);
  while (left <= right) {
    // The part you're missing
    middle = left + Math.floor((right - left) / 2);
    if (sortedArray[middle] === value) {
      return middle;
    }

    if (sortedArray[middle] < value) {
      left = middle + 1;
    }

    if (sortedArray[middle] > value) {
      right = middle - 1;
    }
  }

  return -1;
};

console.log(binarySearch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 4));
```

Comment: I had to make it while left <= right because when I search for 5, it does not find, it the index just goes to 3 , not 4, or am I wrong here, thanks for the help

Comment: That is correct, I missed that out actually... I corrected it now in the code piece... But the main part is to update the middle pointer accordingly in each case....